# Calculating Time Difference from Start/Stop Times in Excel 2007

Tags: excel-2007

I have an excel problem. There are two times in the excel file - `"start time"` and `"restore time"`. The time is actually in `date/time` format like this - `"2013-3-17 12:06:26".`

How can I minus these two times and put the difference in an unused column?

```
Start time - 2013-3-17 12:06:26 Restore time - 2013-3-17 12:07:57
```

Answer should ideally be (in a new column named outage time) `0days 1m 31s or just 1m 31s`.

Here's the sample file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/pf06ese53ybdveg/sample.xlsx

I would really appreciate any help on this. I'm not sure if it will require a macro or formula use, so I'm just asking it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values in the sample file are real date/time values, so you can use a formula like

```
=E2-C2
```

to calculate the time difference. Format the result with the custom format

```
d \da\y(\s), h \hr, mm \m, ss \s
```

or just

```
d \da\y(\s), h:mm:ss
```